# How to run application after installing exe file in ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

new in ubuntu here (ubuntu 18.04). I am trying to install and run an online dictionary application.
I downloaded the exe file and ran it using:

```
sudo apt install mono-runtime
mono EA_es-gr_setup.exe
```

It seems to work, however, I don't know how to proceed from here, the app does not appear in the available applications. Any advice?

Comment: In general, you can't run `.exe` files in Linux. `.exe` files are applications for Windows. Some Windows applications can be run using WINE, as said in nbux's answer, but it depends on the application - you can't assume that any application will run.

Comment: Visit the Wine support site and see the list of supported programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don' think mono can run *any* `.exe` - it is made for .net-Applications.
Especially since the file you try to run seems to be a setup-/installation-file, I am not sure if mono will work.
You can try installing [WINE](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-wine-on-ubuntu-20-04/) or [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/) and install & run the dictionary application with that.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer. If this was an answer it would have complete instructions of how to do the asked question.